# How to order a list from Firestore by a String field (how to parse to int)

Tags: firebase, flutter, sorting, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of things in my flutter app and I want to sort it by day, but in firestore, I'm storing 'day' as string and with it I cant do `orderBy("day")`.. How could I do a `int.parse()`in this field and makes it sort the list?

```
await databaseReference
        .collection("events").doc('admin').collection('sodas').doc(year.toString()).collection(month.toString())
        .orderBy("day")
```

The day in Firestore is like 30, 20,19,28... But its format is string

Comment: Question Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String values in Firestore are sorted by their lexicographical order, so that'd be:

- "1"
- "10"
- "11"
- "12"
- ...
- "18"
- "19"
- "2"
- "20"
- "21"
- ...

The two ways to get the right results are:

- Store the numbers as actual numeric values, so that Firestore uses a numerical sort order for them.
- Store the numbers in a string format that gives the result you want when lexicographically ordered, by left-padding the numbers. For example, when padded with `"0"`:
- "01"
- "02"
- ...
- "09"
- "10"
- "11"
- "12"
- "13"
- ...
- "18"
- "19"
- "20"
- "21"
- ...